# @OrderBy ignored by hibernate & eclipselink?

Tags: hibernate, sorting, sql-order-by, eclipselink

I was testing @OrderBy with an @ElementCollection and it doesn't seem to work.
I retrieve the entity that owns the element collection and I print the collection, it doesn't sort anything ..

```
@Entity
public class AtAsOverride

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "Strings")
@OrderBy(value="stringuri desc") // tried everything: without any value, strings, stringuri ..
private List<String> stringuri;

Query qq = em.createQuery("Select a from AtAsOverride a");
System.out.println(AtAsOverride.class.cast(qq.getResultList().get(0)).getStringuri());
```

Comment: You are going to have to give quite a bit more information.  Like, minimally, how about the mapping snippet showing the collection and its annotations?

Comment: here u go, I edited the question. It's normal mappings.

Comment: stringuri is not an element within the collection and so could be the problem - if you turn EclipseLink logging on I'm sure you would get a warning indicating what the problem is when processing the  AtAsOverride entity.  Try using just the OrderBy without attempting to specify a field.

Comment: as the description says, i tried all permutations :) // tried everything: without any value, strings, stringuri ..

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of EclipseLink allow @OrderBy("desc") and @OrderBy("asc") on basic ElementCollections.
Previously this would be ignored.

Try the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

Just use @OrderBy("desc") or @OrderBy("asc") because it is primitive type. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

By JPA spec, @OrderBy on a ElementCollection of basic type (which is what you have) should not specify any value.  Meaning, it should simply be:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "Strings")
@OrderBy
private List<String> stringuri;
```

which should indicate that "the ordering will be by value of the basic objects".  This is covered in section 11.1.38

Comment: Thanks. But if you want DESC ?

Comment: That is not covered by the spec.  Based on what others have already pointed out, it seems like EclipseLink added some capability for allowing @OrderBy("desc").  Hibernate does not have that capability

Comment: well, I added in the DB the values in desc order, and I put @OrderBy simple, and still no luck.

Comment: Well this is obviously not a issue tracker for either Hibernate nor EclipseLink.